# Entity Framework Mapping, Annotations and general inforation

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, annotations

I have a *(I hope)* basic problem in using Entity Framework with an WPF application.

I followed the msdn walkthrough : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620
and it says:

> Many developers would rather use Data Annotations than the fluent API
>   to perform configuration.

What I understand in that is that the Mapping "folder" with all the mapping classes is useless and that people prefere using annotion directly in Model classes.

So from here, either I'm correct and I want to get rid of the mapping classes

Or I'm wrong and maybe, I need some kind of guid line to start using entity framework

I choose code first approche because I work on an existing database.
The problem is that their are so many approach to work with EF that i'm quite confused.

- Some people are using Edmx files
- Others use reverse engineering
- Annotation
- Fluent api

I can't find an really complete book, or documentation, fundamental guide of any kind for the latest version of EF .

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well for a basic starter I would suggest you try code first as it is easy to start with, simply define your entities as c# classes and later when included in data context they will automatically create your database. What I like about codefirst that is easy for most common cases and quick to implement. Also migration has some automation. I suggest you read this [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx).

Comment: So should i forget about the "reverse engineering" funcionality from the power tools ?

Comment: You need to read more about the EF as probably you are not understanding it clear enough. What kind of mapping classes do you have in mind ? Because in code first you use your model classes and thats it. In the blog link i posted there is a good example how everything works and how you can implement it.

Comment: I have in mind the : "Configuration classes" that come along with the reverse engineering tool. in the link i provided the are talking about annontion vs flent api, i thought that if you want to go with annotations you dont need those "configurations class" anymore 

i hope i m clear enough because english is not my native language :/

Comment: Now with the latest EF version what you only need to do is to define your classes, ad them to context as DBSets and finally pass a connection string to a database. EF will automatically create the databse with all the mappings under the hood and you will not need to bother thinking about those. Unless you want to map not all the fields from the table then you should use annotations in your EF code first clases.